# Scaling normal distributions only using the data

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, variance

Suppose that you have the following data:

$$ X=\left\lbrack x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right\rbrack $$ that is normal distributed N(0,1)

$$ X\sim N\left(0,1\right) $$

To change the mean you will have to add a number in every element:

$$ X+Y=Z $$

The mean-value will now be Y.

Question:

Is there any way to manipulate the data so that you will change the variance?

Comment: Yes. If $Y$ follows a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$ follows a $N(0,1)$ distribution. Consequently, if $X\sim N(0,1)$, then $\sigma X + \mu$ follows a $N(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

Comment: This answered the question. Thank you.

Comment: To change the variance you can multiply the random variable by a constant c. Then $cX\sim \mathcal N(0, c^2)$

Comment: @Gutiérrez $\sigma X+\mu \sim \mathcal N(\mu , \sigma^{\color{red}2}) $

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this isn't special to the normal distribution.  If $X$ follows _any_ distribution and has variance $1$, then $cX$ has variance $c^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 important points in your question related to $X$, with $E(X)=0$ and $V(X)=1$, and $Y=\sigma X+\mu$:

1. irrespective to the distribution of $X$, $E(Y)=\mu$ and
   $V(Y)=\sigma^2$. This is valid for all distributions in which $E(X)=0$ and
   $V(X)=1$. And it is valid the other way around: if $Y$ is a random variable with any distribution in which $E(Y)=\mu$ and $V(Y)=\sigma^2$, and $X=\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$, it is true that $E(X)=0$ and $V(X)=1$.
2. The probability distribution of $Y=\sigma X+\mu$ is Normal if $X$ is Normal. This is not an obvious fact. The preservation of the distribution under linear afine transformations is a property of the Normal that is not necessarily shared by other distributions.